# Get the current logged in OS user in Adobe Air

Tags: apache-flex, air

I need the name of the current logged in user in my **Air/Flex** application. The application will only be deployed on Windows machines. I think I could attain this by regexing the User directory, but am open to other ways.

Answer (score 10):

There's a couple of small cleanups you can make...

```
package
{
    import flash.filesystem.File;

    public class UserUtil
    {
        public static function get currentOSUser():String
        {
            var userDir:String = File.userDirectory.nativePath;
            var userName:String = userDir.substr(userDir.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);
            return userName;
        }
    }
}
```

As Kevin suggested, use `File.separator` to make the directory splitting cross-platform (just tested on Windows and Mac OS X).

You don't need to use `resolvePath("")` unless you're looking for a child.

Also, making the function a proper getter allows binding without any further work.

In the above example I put it into a `UserUtil` class, now I can bind to `UserUtil.currentOSUser`, e.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Label text="{UserUtil.currentOSUser}"/> 
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: This solution doesnť work when the user has different login name and home directory name, which is common when OS is reinstalled or migrated. Does anyone know another solution. Please help.

Answer (score 9):

Also I would try:

```
File.userDirectory.name
```

But I don't have Air installed so I can't really test this...

Comment: Works perfectly fine on Windows XP. Will it provide the same for Vista, Windows 7 and iMac?

Comment: Works for me on Win 7

Answer (score 5):

This isn't the prettiest approach, but if you know your AIR app will only be run in a Windows environment it works well enough:

```
public var username:String;

public function getCurrentOSUser():void
{       
   var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();  
   var file:File = new File("C:/WINDOWS/system32/whoami.exe");
   nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

   process = new NativeProcess();       
   process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
   process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
}

public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
{           
   var output:String = process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);
   this.username = output.split('\\')[1];
   trace("Got username: ", this.username);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works in XP / Vista, but is definitely expandable to OSX, linux, I'd still be interested in another way.

```
public static function GetCurrentOSUser():String{
    // XP & Vista only.
    var userDirectory:String = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("").nativePath;
    var startIndex:Number = userDirectory.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1
    var stopIndex:Number = userDirectory.length;
    var user = userDirectory.substring(startIndex, stopIndex);

    return user;
}
```

Comment: May want to replace `"\\"` with `File.separator` to make it work on linux.

Answer (score -1):

Update way later: there's actually a built in function to get the current user. I think it's in nativeApplication.

Comment: I need to get the current user too, but can't find that function... can you share the solution?

Comment: There is nothing mentioned in http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html