# flex air app - Get User's AD domain

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex4

Using Flex 4 / Air 2.0.3

Is it possible to get the active directory domain name associated with the logged on user?

This page ([Get the current logged in OS user in Adobe Air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376/get-the-current-logged-in-os-user-in-adobe-air)) shows the user name can be inferred from the user directory folder name, however is there a way to get the domain name?  (This is assuming the user is part of a domain!)

Assuming I am part of a domain "office" and my login is "j.jones", I want to retrieve both the "j.jones" and the "office" parts.

Thank you,

Jonsie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIR 2.0 is able to run native processes and read their standard output. So, if your machine has AD console tools installed, you could run **dsget user** from AIR and read result. Also, you could take tools with your program (I have had creating AIR distribs bundled with java runtime).

Comment: Sounds great, but I'd hate to rely on these being installed. But gives me a great idea - if I read the output of "echo %USERDOMAIN%" I can get this value without external deps.... Any idea of the equivalent on 'nix / mac?

Comment: uname or hostname? I'm not that strong in linux script, but there should be something.

Comment: Both would be great, although domain name ideally, as, worst case the username can be inferred from the user directory folder name.

Either way I feel this approach is the winner!

Comment: @jobbie jones. `echo -n $HOSTNAME` and `echo -n $USERNAME` work fine in bash under cygwin. Not sure if this works in every case, though. I'm not a *nix guy myself.

Comment: Hereos.  Thank you all for the input!  Gotta love SO

Answer (score 0):

I have make this class:

```
public class UserDomainWindows extends EventDispatcher
{
    public static const EVENT_COMPLETE:String = "complete";

    private var process:NativeProcess;
    private var file:File;

    public function UserDomainWindows() 
    {

    }

    public function get():void {
        file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("_getuserdomain.cmd");
        var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);

        fs.writeUTFBytes("@echo off\r\n");
        fs.writeUTFBytes("echo %username%\r\n");
        fs.writeUTFBytes("echo %userdomain%");

        fs.close();
        getCurrentOSUser();
    }

    private function getCurrentOSUser():void
    {       
        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo(); 
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

        process = new NativeProcess();       
        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
        process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
    }

    private function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
    {           
        var output:String = process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);
        file.deleteFile();
        var sz:Array = output.split("\r\n");
        this.dispatchEvent(new UserDomainWindowsEvent("complete", sz[0], sz[1]));
    }
}
```

and this event class:

```
public class UserDomainWindowsEvent extends Event 
{
    public var username:String;
    public var userdomain:String;

    public function UserDomainWindowsEvent(type:String, username:String, userdomain:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false) 
    { 
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        this.userdomain = userdomain;
        this.username = username;
    } 

    public override function clone():Event 
    { 
        return new UserDomainWindowsEvent(type, this.username, this.userdomain, bubbles, cancelable);
    } 

    public override function toString():String 
    { 
        return formatToString("UserDomainWindowsEvent", "type", "username", "userdomain", "bubbles", "cancelable", "eventPhase"); 
    }

}
```

example:

```
    public function Main():void 
    {
        var ud:UserDomainWindows = new UserDomainWindows();
        ud.addEventListener(UserDomainWindows.EVENT_COMPLETE, onGetUserDomain);
        ud.get();
    }

    private function onGetUserDomain(e:UserDomainWindowsEvent):void {
        trace("username: " + e.username);
        trace("userdomain: " + e.userdomain);

    }
```