# How are you able to grab the Window NT Logged User Name using Flex/Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript, apache-flex, credentials

How are you able to grab the Window NT Logged User Name using Flex/Actionscript. I have worked with attaining these credentials in ASP.NET, but I am new to the realm of Flex and need some assistance

***ASP.NET*** code looks as follows

```
Getting the User Name :

using three ways we can get the User Name using C#

1) System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal p = 
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;

string strName = p.Identity.Name;

[ OR ]

2) string strName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

[ OR ]

3) string strName = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"]; //Finding with name

string strName = Request.ServerVariables[5]; //Finding with index
```

Comment: I believe this question should be closed as it's a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376/get-the-current-logged-in-os-user-in-adobe-air

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The post was verry helpful. When I was searching I didnt see this topic the way I worded. Appreciate it alot!

Answer (score 0):

Never seen any sort of access like that in Air and would not imagine you would ever be allowed (permissions) in Flex

you could possibly achieve the desired result using sockets?
In AIr there is a SocketMonitor for this.

You can connect to specific port on machine and send and recieve data.

So you can create only a workaround: create a listener in C# and create a connection from this listener to your flex application.

Comment: I will check this way out soon. This will cause us to create another layer on the Application Architecture so will let you know. Wouldn't be out the way though do accomplish this....