# AS3: Get name of computer login

Tags: actionscript-3

Just a quick question, I googled around for a bit but everything resulted in other AS3 tidbits.

Is it at all possible to access a user's computer logon name from AS3? I wouldn't have assumed so but given we can access other information directly from the computer (eg date), I just wondered if it was possible.

Thanks!
Harry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the web, I believe you can't get such an info.

If you are working on the desktop with AIR, you may retrieve the user's directory with

```
File.userDirectory
```

and its name which should be the same as the user's

```
File.userDirectory.name
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd love to know the login of the user, but also his password.

I think it's not desirable to be able to get such information, especially from a client-side script. This is possible with *ASP.NET* using [Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx). When the user is authenticated you can use `User.Identity.Name`. It should be possible to write that name to the front-end, and you can pass that to Flash using [ExternalInterFace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

If you are using Adobe Air, it is easier to grab the users name, since you have access to the users filesystem. See [Get the current logged in OS user in Adobe Air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376/get-the-current-logged-in-os-user-in-adobe-air).

Btw, on the web, it is not an unusual question to ask the user what his (user)name is.